# How can i fill json model correctly by javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

i have been filling a json model from another json. but it is filling last element. if i put my result on screen. it produces the same "NAME" that equals to "3". look inside of for loop: console.log(griddatalist.items[i].Name);How can i fill by using "PUSH" method for list of object as a json?

```
var result = { };
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Can you try formatting the code in your question such that it is readable and make your question clearer.

Comment: ok. i got it. if you run my code jsfiddle, you will se the same result. "3","3","3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change just one line.

Put the line **var griddata = {};** into the for loop - see your modified code below:

```
var result = { };
```